# Unable to import multiple .cmp files

Tags: powershell, import

I have run the command

```
 Export-SPWeb -Identity  $url -ItemUrl $largeList -CompressionSize 15 -Path "c:\itemFolder\backup.cmp"
```

This results in 3 files.

```
 c:\itemFolder\backup.cmp
 c:\itemFolder\backup1.cmp 
 c:\itemFolder\backup2.cmp
```

Now when I try to Import these files the second two fail. Error message: "Import-SPWeb : Failed to read package"

Log file has another error message :

```
 The file operation of c:\itemFolder\backup1.cmp was preformed out of order. The file was operated on as order 1 but was marked as order 0. Please ensure these files are operated on sequentially starting from 0
```

I do import-spweb once per file, in order. Why is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you export a site / web, it created one or multiple CMP files depend upon the Size of Site and value of [FileMaxSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.deployment.spexportsettings.filemaxsize(v=office.14).aspx)

> By default, the .cmp files are limited to 24 MB in size, although you
>   can change this value using the FileMaxSize property. If set to zero,
>   the value resets to the default. When site data exceeds the specified
>   limit, site data is separated in to two or more migration files.
>   However, if a single site data file exceeds the maximum file size, the
>   operation does not split the source file, but rather it resizes the
>   .cmp file to accommodate the oversize file. You can have any number of
>
> ### > .cmp files.

When there are multiple .cmp files, the file names are appended numerically. For example, where the baseFileName parameter is "MyWeb", and where the export operation produces multiple .cmp files, the migration packages are named "MyWeb1.cmp", "MyWeb2.cmp", and so forth.

**IN NutSHell**, you dont need to import each file individually rather you just need to run the import. In your case your Import command should be like this...

```
Import-SPWeb http://site.com -Path "c:\itemFolder\backup.cmp" -UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

Comment: Sarwar, my Export command has created more than 20 .cmp files. Now, while importing these files Do I have to run Import command for every single cmp file or Running it for only First cmp file will do the work?

Comment: put all cmp file in a folder and point it to the very 1st one, command will automatically pick others

Comment: Thank you for that. I have 1 SiteCollection, in which I want to split 1 subsite of size 100 GB+ and create new site collection with new content Db on same webApplication. I am not sure whether Export Import command will work for this volume of data. Thank you in advance